# HTML not processing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

We are working on a dApp that is giving us problems. The site loads OK and the button to open the subform ("Post My Rental") works. When I fill out the subform and click the 'submit' button, nothing happens. I have confirmed that I am connected to Metamask and Ganache, but no transaction goes through. Checking inspect in Chrome, no errors there. I suspect there is something missing in this code, but I can't find it. If you could help out, we would really appreciate it. Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Rent My Place</title>
<!-- Title will appear as a tab in browser on webpage -->
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Application -->
  <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- stylesheet refers to the look of the page, Font, color-->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- container that contains title panel-->
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
<p style="font-size:80px;padding: 1em;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border:10px;border-style:solid;border-color:#c3c3c3;">
      <font color = "#880015" >Rent My Place</font></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12" id="article-list">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!--<p id="account" class="welcome pull-right"></p>
          <p id="accountBalance" class="welcome pull-left"></p>-->
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
          <div class="panel-title">
            <p style="font-size:24px;padding: 1em;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px; border:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:#c3c3c3;">
                  <font color = "#880015">Renter's Tip: </font><font color = "#000000">Inspect the property before you send money.</font><br><font color = "#880015">Landlord's Tip: </font><font color = "#000000">Meet prospective tenants in person.</font></p>
            <!-- Button that opens second window to a form to fill out-->
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sellArticle">Post a Rental</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- when the event button gets click, it will show the list-->
        <ul id="events" class="collapse list-group"></ul>
      </div>

      <div id="articlesRow" class="row">
        <!-- ARTICLES with pertinent item information LOAD HERE -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--Result that is displayed after input-->
  <div id="articleTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default panel-article">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <strong>Beds</strong>: <span class="beds"></span><br/>
          <strong>Baths</strong>: <span class="baths"></span><br/>
          <strong>Address</strong>: <span class="propaddress"></span><br/>
          <strong>Rental Price</strong>: <span class="rental_price"></span><br/>
          <strong>Description</strong>: <span class="article_description"></span><br/>
          <strong>Property is available for showing</strong>: <span class="available"></span><br/>
          <strong>Contact Email</strong>: <span class="contact_email"></span><br/>
          <!--<strong>Sold by</strong>: <span class="article-seller"></span><br/>-->
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <button type="button" class= "btn btn-primary btn-success btn-buy" onclick="App.buyArticle(); return false;">Buy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <!-- Modal form to sell an article -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="sellArticle" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Rent Your Place</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--NOTE: For radio buttons to work, 'name' field must match-->
                  <label for="property_type">Property Type</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="property" id="property_type" value="house" > House
                  <input type="radio" name="property" id="property_type" value="apartment" > Apartment
                  <input type="radio" name="property" id="property_type" value="duplex" > Duplex
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="propaddress">Address</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="propaddress" placeholder="Enter the address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="beds">Beds</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="beds" value="0"> Studio
                  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="beds" value="1"> One
                  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="beds" value="2"> Two
                  <input type="radio" name="beds" id="beds" value="3"> Three +
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="baths">Baths</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="baths" value="1"> One
                  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="baths" value="2"> Two
                  <input type="radio" name="baths" id="baths" value="3"> Three +
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="rental_price">Rent (in USD)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rental_price" placeholder="$" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="description">Description</label>
                  <textarea type="text" class="form-control vresize" id="article_description" placeholder="Describe your property" maxlength="255"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="available"></label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="available" value="available" id="available"> Property is available for showing
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="contact_email">Contact Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_email" placeholder="Enter your contact email">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="App.sellArticle(); return false;">Submit</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <div class="navbar-inner navbar-content-center text-center">
        <p class="text-muted" credit><a href="http://www.axbean.com">AXbean</a> - &copy; 2018</a></p>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/OurRentalManualInputDataInitWeb3appMay22.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the app.js that is called:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},
  account: 0x0,
  loading: false,

  init: function() {
    return App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: function() {
    // initialize web3
    if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
      //reuse the provider of the Web3 object injected by Metamask
      App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    } else {
      //create a new provider and plug it directly into our local node
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    App.displayAccountInfo();

    return App.initContract();
  },

  displayAccountInfo: function() {
    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if(err === null) {
        App.account = account;
        $('#account').text(account);
        web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(err, balance) {
          if(err === null) {
            $('#accountBalance').text(web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ETH");
          }
        })
      }
    });
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.json', function(chainListArtifact) {
      //added May24 to json file name
      // get the contract artifact file and use it to instantiate a truffle contract abstraction
      App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24 = TruffleContract(chainListArtifact);
      // set the provider for our contracts
      App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
      // listen to events
      App.listenToEvents();
      // retrieve the article from the contract
      return App.reloadArticles();
    });
  },

  reloadArticles: function() {
    //avoid reentry bugs
    if(App.loading){
      return;
    }
    App.loading = true;

    // refresh account information because the balance might have changed
    App.displayAccountInfo();

    var chainListInstance;

    App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      chainListInstance = instance;
      return chainListInstance.getArticlesForSale();
    }).then(function(articlesIds) {

      // retrieve the article placeholder and clear it
      $('#articlesRow').empty();

      for(var i = 0; i < articlesIds.length; i++){
        var articleId = articlesIds[i];
        chainListInstance.articles(articleId.toNumber()).then(function(article){
          App.displayArticle(article[0], article[1], article[3], article[4], article[5]);
        });
      }
      App.loading = false;

    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      App.loading = false;
    });
  },

  displayArticle: function(id, seller, beds, baths, propaddress, rental_price, description, available, contact_email){
    var articlesRow = $('#articlesRow');

    var etherPrice = web3.fromWei(price, "ether");

    var articleTemplate = $("#articleTemplate");
    //articleTemplate.find('.panel-title').text(name);
    articleTemplate.find('.beds').text(beds);
    articleTemplate.find('.baths').text(baths);
    articleTemplate.find('.propaddress').text(propaddress);
    articleTemplate.find('.rental_price').text(rental_price);
    articleTemplate.find('.description').text(description);
    articleTemplate.find('.available').text(available);
    articleTemplate.find('.contact_email').text(contact_email);
  //  articleTemplate.find('.article_price').text(etherPrice + " ETH");
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-id', id);
    articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').attr('data-value', etherPrice);

    //seller
    if(seller == App.account){
      articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text("You");
      articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').hide();
    }else{
      articleTemplate.find('.article-seller').text(seller);
      articleTemplate.find('.btn-buy').show();
    }
    //add this new article
    articlesRow.append(articleTemplate.html());
  },

  sellArticle: function() {
    // retrieve the detail of the article
  //  var _article_name = $('#article_name').val();
    var _description = $('#description').val();
    var _beds = $('#beds').val();
    var _baths = $('#baths').val();
    var _propaddress = $('#propaddress').val();
    var _rental_price = $('#rental_price').val();
    var _property_type = $('#property_type').val();
    var _available = $('#available').val();
    var _contact_email = $('#contact_email').val();
  //  var _article_price = $('#article_price').val();
  //  var _price = web3.toWei(parseFloat($('#article_price').val() || 0), "ether");

    //if((_article_name.trim() == '') || (_price == 0)) {
      // nothing to sell
    //  return false;
  //  }

    App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      return instance.sellArticle(_description, _beds, _baths, _propaddress, _rental_price, _property_type, _available, _contact_email, {
        from: App.account,
        gas: 500000
      });
    }).then(function(result) {

    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  },

  // listen to events triggered by the contract
  listenToEvents: function() {
    App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      instance.LogSellArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
        if (!error) {
          $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._name + ' is now for sale</li>');
        } else {
          console.error(error);
        }
        App.reloadArticles();
      });

      instance.LogBuyArticle({}, {}).watch(function(error, event) {
        if (!error) {
          $("#events").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + event.args._buyer + ' bought ' + event.args._name + '</li>');
        } else {
          console.error(error);
        }
        App.reloadArticles();
      });
    });
  },

  buyArticle: function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    // retrieve the article price and data
    var _articleId = $(event.target).data('id');
    var _price = parseFloat($(event.target).data('value'));

    App.contracts.OurRentalTestFromClassMay24.deployed().then(function(instance){
      return instance.buyArticle(_articleId, {
        from: App.account,
        value: web3.toWei(_price, "ether"),
        gas: 500000
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```